# Crookes Radiometer turning by mechanical stimulation?

Tags: electromagnetism

Most people know the Crookes Radiometer, or the light mill. I have made a series of vexing videos showing it being brought to turn very fast by shaking or tapping it vertically on a surface such as a table top. However, this is in conflict with everything I have ever read, formerly experienced or researched on this topic. Of course the purpose and descriptions of the Crookes are well known that electromagnetic visible (light) and non-visible radiations causes it to spin.
I believe there to be some confounding variables here to my experiment. Otherwise this would possibly have to viewed as a quite novel result in a field very extensively researched. Which I highly doubt.
Has anybody ever had any experiences or knows any research that stimulating the Crookes by mechanical force can cause it to spin vigorously?

Would anybody with a physics degree be prepared to state that the Crookes Radiometer cannot be brought to a very high rate of spin by involuntary shaking of the hand or vertical tapping on a surface, that is perpendicular to the axis of the spinning arms? Or to conduct a short replication/disprove themselves?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to spin up a crookes radiometer by hand, using exactly the same technique as that used to keep a hula hoop in motion around your waist.

This is because the crookes device uses a gravity-preloaded pinpoint pivot bearing which allows the rotational axis of the paddlewheel to tilt off-center, so its center of mass is shifted off-center- and this will allow an external shaking motion to develop a torque on the paddlewheel and spin it up.

Comment: Sort of what I was about to post. I think there is an inverted (glass) bowl sitting on a pin. If the pinpoint is moved in a horizontal circle, I expect the vane to rotate.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: A certain, however not extreme turn rate might be feasible to achieve. Even so, it would have to be a conscious, dedicated and wilfully rhythmic movement
Could an extreme turn rate could regularly bei achieved by mit intended, uncoordinated horizontal shaking ?
My experiment however achieves an extreme turn rate by vertically tapping the Crookes radiometer on a flat surface such as a table. That is by a movement perpendicular to the axis of the wheel.
To stay in the hoola hoop picture: this would be Akin to jumping Up sind down to keep the hoola hoop turning.
This obviously would notwork

Answer (score 0):

I've also been able to cause the radiometer vanes to spin immediately and rapidly by jiggling the table it's sitting on. Essentially it's suspended on a post on the table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).